# Load overlay later or on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

I created a website for a festival and they got a lot of artists. For each artist I created a div overlay which is loaded directly. It worked fine but since the festival gets more and more artists, the page performance is pretty weak.

Is there a way to load the complete overlay on a click?
I already tried different lazy loads but they won't work because there is no scroll-event.

You can have a closer look at the website here: http://www.pulsopenair.de/program.html

I'm really looking forward to your answers.

Best,
Dominik

Comment: You might be able to load what you need in a `$(elem).on("click", function(){yourLoadStuff(); });` or something

Comment: This is too broad a question. If you have a specific issue in mind within your page it would be helpful to us and you if you provided us with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Create a hidden button or something and trigger click after page loads, add an event listener to it like @MartijnVissers said. then do whatever you want inside that event function. But if you truly care about the performance then these are some of the common things to consider: less JS/image more CSS/svg(usually, but if you have to use image then create different versions for different screens), less JS/CSS library means less http calls, minimize your custom JS/CSS in production.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to implement your overlay using [css animation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) and [css 3D transforms](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp) instead of js ? That may be enough to improve your page performance